# AJAX isn't posting to controller method

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

On my view page I have it where a user can click my 'Add Part' button to add the part they selected from the dropdown. This looks like this

```
  <div id="Part" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.DropDownList("PartID", null, "-- Select --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control chosen-select Part-select" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="button" value="Add Part" class="btn" onclick="add()"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see it includes my button that should call my add() JavaScript function that looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function add() {
            var token = $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']", "#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm").val();

            var parts = [];
          

            // Get all part ids and store them in arrays           
            var partssel = document.getElementsByClassName("Part-select");
 
            for (i = 0; i < partssel.length; i++) {
                parts[i] = partssel[i].options[partssel[i].selectedIndex].value;
            }
           alert("I am an alert box!");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@IGT.baseUrl/JODetailsAjax/AddUnits",
                traditional: true,
                data: {
                    __RequestVerificationToken: token,
                    jo_id: @Model.Id,
                    addPart_id: parts
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success === "False") {
                        var errorMessage = data.Message;
                        alert("Error: " + errorMessage);
                        return;
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {
                    alert("Error:" + error);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

I verified it's running the method as it hits the Alert, but when it goes through the AJAX section of it, it always returns the 'error' alert in the AJAX method instead of going to my POST Method in my controller. (I verified it's not hitting my POST method by putting a breakpoint at the beginning of it)

Here is what is showing in the network tab of my developer console

[image: Network]

Why is this not working?

Comment: What's the error?  In your browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, what is the AJAX request being made and what is the server's response?

Comment: @David The error it's hitting is the 'error' in my AJAX call. And I have updated my question

Comment: An HTTP 500 code means there was an error on the server.  When you click on that line in the browser's debugging network tab, what is the content of the response from the server?  Does it contain information about the error?  If not, you may need to adjust your web config to show error messages.  (It normally does this by default for debug environments.)

Comment: @David Oh yes I see what you mean, it says "The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present."

Comment: Is the value for `token` being sent to the server?  Is that value what you expect?

Comment: No for some reason the token isn't being sent to the server @David. I think I may have found the issue though. I'll let you know

Comment: Each step of debugging leads to the next step of debugging... In the browser's debugging tools you can use the script debugger to place a breakpoint inside your JavaScript function and debug it.  When you do that, what is the runtime value for the `token` variable?  If it has no value, then your selector isn't finding the element you expect it to.  From there you'll need to examine the HTML to identify the element you're looking for.  Each time you find something you don't expect while debugging, trace where it came from.

Comment: Thanks David for your help! Yeah I just didn't really know how to debug an ajax call like that as I'm a beginner but with the advice you gave me I was able to diagnose what the problem was. Thank-you!